# Tuples and Strings, Problems with splitting a tuple into a string so that it can be split?

Tags: python, string, csv

I have taken a CSV file and put it into a a tuple, however, I need to split a string within the tuple and do not know how. Can someone please tell me what I need to do to fix it?

My current code is:

```
import csv

with open('scallop.csv','rU') as scallop:

    reader=csv.reader(scallop)
    data=[tuple(line) for line in reader]
    print data[1]     

    beam=raw_input("Please input the beam specifications you would like to search for: ")

    for line in data: #need to rewrite
        data.index(beam,)
        print line
    else:
        print("\nNo beam found")
```

The beam cannot be found because it is attached to another one, input file is formatted like this:

```
('-55', '158.75', '-54.975', '158.775', '*', '1AB073C1|1BB073C1', 'Vsat-Antenna-1|Vsat-Antenna-1', 'BUC-1|BUC-1')
```

When inputing the beam you would like use the format

```
1AB021C1
```

where:

- 1A is the Satellite,
- B021 is the Beam followed by a 3 digit number
- and C1 is the Channel followed by a single number.

Here is my script's output:

```
Please input the beam specifications you would like to search for: 1AB073C1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sasha/Documents/workspace/RoO1/RoO2.py", line 17, in <module>
    data.index(beam,)
ValueError: '1AB073C1' is not in list
```

Comment: Don't you know how to access a value in a tuple? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm

Comment: It is from a csv file with over a million pieces

Comment: @XORcist His problem is that he needs to check all the elements of the tuple to see if they're a partial match for his input. I don't think it's trivial (for a beginner to Python).

Comment: So how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This snippet should work:

```
for line in data: #need to rewrite
    if any(item for item in data if beam in item):
        print line
else:
    print("No beam found")
```

This way, you check every element of the line, and see if any of them contain the data for your beam. I assume that nothing will be strangely formatted so that it contains a beam but shouldn't match.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sasha/Documents/workspace/RoO1/RoO2.py", line 12, in <module>
    if any([item for item in data.items() if beam in item]):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: @user3760838 Try it now. I misread the documentation and I thought you had a `csv.DictReader`.

Comment: Remove `[]` from `any()` to prevent unnecessary list creation.

Comment: @200OK Fixed, thanks, that syntax always confuses me a little.

Comment: @200OK do you see any of those instances in my code?